# protobuf c++ to java Serialization by binary file

Tags: java, c++, parsing, protocol-buffers, binaryfiles

I serialize data with protobuf in C++. By writing binary data to a docs file (.docs), these data generated on C++'s program in Ubuntu.

Then I try to use these data in java program in windows by parseFrom(new FileInputStream(path)), but I can't get correct data.

C++ serialization:

```
std::ofstream outfile;
outfile.open(filename, std::ios::binary | std::ios::out);
if (outfile.is_open()) {
    if (!docs.SerializeToOstream(&outfile)) {
        LOG(INFO) << "serial to ostream fail";
    }
```

write to filename.docs.

java parsing:

```
CrawlDocs crawl_docs = CrawlDocs.parseFrom(new FileInputStream(file_path));
System.out.println(crawl_docs.toString());
```

and the result:

[image]

I found some \282\214 chracters, Is it that because I am using the wrong pairs of API? Or is it a coding problem due to different systems? Or java's toString() is different from C++'s DebugString()?

And this is mydata is from spider:

```
crawldoc.content = item["content"]
```

Comment: it *should* work... as a quick "narrow it down" thing, you could use https://protogen.marcgravell.com/decode (it has a file upload button) to try and verify the file you've generated; this will quickly tell you whether the issue is read vs write...

Comment: thanks,I tried this tool. No errors occurred. I don't know if this means that my data is no problem!

Comment: that probably means the problem is in the java "read" code... that's a 50% reduction in places to look, at least :/